# How to show that $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1} ^2 -1}{a_n}$ . is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1} ^2  -1}{a_n}$  be a sequence of real numbers where $a_n>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$. It is given that $a_1=1 , a_2=b>0$. It is given that $1<b<2$ .Is it possible to show that $a_n$ is bounded from this given information?

Comment: What's the value of $a_0$?

Comment: You don't need $a_0$ actually

Comment: @MathsFreak So $a_0 = c$ is an arbitrary real number? Or does your sequence start from $a_1$?

Comment: Yes it starts from $n=1$

Comment: @MathsFreak Then you should edit the phrase "$n \in \mathbb{N}$" to "$n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$". The set $\mathbb{N}$ usually begins at $0$, so it will confuse people like MrMaths above.

Comment: ok edited the question

Comment: If we select $b=1$ then $a_3=0$, which may create a problem for $a_5$.  Need a tighter constraint on $b$ to avoid this breakdown.

Comment: If $b=2$ then $a_n=n$ which diverges. If $b>2$ then $a_n>n$.

Comment: Sorry guys there is something more about $b$

Comment: see the edited post

Comment: In order to ensure convergence, I guess we need the condition that $b<1$. I mean, if $b<1$, then $\{a_n\}$ will converge for sure.

Comment: @Kolmogorov It's not obvious to me if $b<1, a_n$ converges for sure. First it can't converge to a positive number $a$ (else $a=\frac{a^2-1}{a}$). I tried a few cases $b<1$ in a spreadsheet and ${a_n}$ is all over the place (albeit bounded).

Comment: Pick a random number like $b=1.7$  What does the graph of the $a_n$ look like?

Comment: Numerically, if we set $b=2-\epsilon$, then the bounds seem to be approximately $\pm\sqrt{\epsilon}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Well, bounded or not, it depends on $b$. I won't go in details but will give the outline in the following.

Firstly, you can observe that $ a_{n+2}a_n -a_{n+1}^2= a_{n+1}a_{n-1} -a_n^2$, and this leads to :
$$ \dfrac{a_{n+2}+a_n}{a_{n+1}}= \dfrac{a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}= \dots = \dfrac{a_3+a_1}{a_2} =b$$

So now you have the following recursive relation:
$$ a_{n+2} -ba_{n+1}+a_n=0$$

Solving that, we have some formula of $(a_n)$ as:
$$ a_n= a \phi_1^n+b\phi_2^n$$

And rest is simple, normally, the first necessary condition we would get for the boundedness is $|b| \le 2$.

Comment: +1 clever solution.

Comment: From your result, one can deduce 
$$a_n = U_{n-1}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)
= \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin\theta},& \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) \text{ for } b < 2\\
\frac{\sinh(n\theta)}{\sinh \theta},& \theta = \cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) \text{ for } b > 2 
\end{cases}
$$
 where $U_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ [Chebyshev's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of second kind.

Comment: I didn't know the solution can be that nice. Thank you for having me informed.

Comment: Great solution. One problem is you assumed $a_n \neq 0, \forall n$. This is not guaranteed. For example, $b=1 \implies a_3=0; b=\sqrt 2 \implies a_5=0; b \approx 0.44505 \implies a_7=0$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for all integers $n\geq 1$, $a_n$ will be a rational fraction in
$b$ of degree $n-1$, with leading coefficient $1$ (by that I mean that for all fixed $n\geq 1$, you can write that $a_n\sim b^{n-1}$ as $b$ goes to infinity.

So my intuition is that if $b>1$, then $a_n$ will behave like a diverging geometric sequence.

Comment: Run a spreasheet and your claim is not true for $1<b<2$.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. I should have been more precise. You can prove that for all $n\geq 1$, $a_n$ can be written as $P_n(b)/Q_n(b)$ where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are two polynomials with leading coefficient $1$, and such that the degree of $P$ minus that of $Q$ is $n-1$ (one should check that $a_n$ never vanishes, as long as $b>1$). But this does not imply my previous claim indeed, especially if $b$ is not too large (and here, I see that $b$ must satisfy $1<b<2$...